# Tuna Alternatives

Tags: fish, tuna

I simply love eating tuna, specially with sweet potato, sweet corn and mayonnaise but because tuna isn't good if you eat it everyday, I was wondering what could be best alternative that has good amount of protein in it and taste good or if I need to prepare something for myself but shouldn't be expensive.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've made mock tuna with chickpeas, and vegan mayo (because I'm vegan, you can always use the real stuff). There are a ton of recipes (just search "mock tuna" on Google), [such as this one](http://yeahthatveganshit.blogspot.com/2007/08/mock-tuna-salad.html). Chickpeas are a great source of protein.